# bash: sed processing of the files including leading-zeros

Tags: bash, sed, leading-zero

I am using a bash script to loop over the files pre-defined in several groups of the array within the directory in order to edit the file in case if its exist (for example in the 1st group there are 100 files arranged from 0001 to 0100, in the second group - 50 files arranged from 0001 to 0050 etc).

```
#an array for the groups
systems=(one two three four)

 # loop over the groups
for file in "${systems[@]}"; do  
      i="1"
      # introduce K var because the files are numbered as 0001 ... 0100
      k=$(printf '%03d' $i)
      while [  $i -le 100 ]; do
        if [ ! -f "${output}/${file}_${k}.pdb" ]; then
          echo 'File '${output}/${file}_${k}.pdb' does not exits!'
          break
        else
          ## edit file via SED
          # to add i-th number on the first string of the file and substitute smth on the last string;
          sed -i -e '1 i\MODEL '$i'' -e 's/TER/ENDMDL/g' ${output}/${file}_${k}.pdb
          ((i++))
        fi
      done
done
```

This script doesn't not work on the stage of SED editing, but if I omit usage of the leading zeros in the names of files and use just i-th index within the script, everything works fine:

```
 # loop over the groups
for file in "${systems[@]}"; do  
      i="1"
      # put k into comment since filles arranged from 1 to 100 without leading zeros; 
      #k=$(printf '%03d' $i)
      while [  $i -le 100 ]; do
        # the filles arranged from 1 to 100
        if [ ! -f "${output}/${file}_${i}.pdb" ]; then
          echo 'File '${output}/${file}_${i}.pdb' does not exits!'
          break
        else
          ## edit file via SED
          # to add i-th number on the first string of the file
          sed -i -e '1 i\MODEL '$i'' -e 's/TER/ENDMDL/g' ${output}/${file}_${i}.pdb
          ((i++))
        fi
      done
done
```

Comment: To elaborate jas' response below: `printf -v enumerated "${output}/${file}_%04d.pdb" $i; sed -i -e '1 i\MODEL '$i'' -e 's/TER/ENDMDL/g' $enumerated`

Comment: @PaulHodges please add yours as an answer --- it's much more complete than what I had.

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: have made several edits.

No answers of my own here - just compiling into a single block of code, incorporating the the answers of [jas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229272/jas) (at his request) and [Walter A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3220113/walter-a) who likely hit the real problem -

```
for file in "${systems[@]}"
do for ((i=1;i<100;i++))
   do printf -v enumerated "${output}/${file}_%04d.pdb" $i 
     if [[ -f "$enumerated" ]
     then sed -i -e "1 i\\MODEL $i" -e 's/TER/ENDMDL/g' $enumerated
     else echo "file not found: '$enumerated''
     fi
  done
done
```

Depending on what else is in your directory structure, you might also try this:

```
for stub in "${systems[@]}"
do for file in "$output/${stub}"_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].pdb
   do sed -i -e "1 i\\MODEL ${file//[^0-9]/}" -e 's/TER/ENDMDL/g' "$file"
   done
done
```

Comment: still does not work. in fact it produces correct filles but without any of the sed modifications inside of it. by the way I need to intdocuse within the file on the first string a value without leading zeros (as was shown in my first example). that is why in my first post I proposed to define k and i (without zeros) as two different variables

Comment: Need to see examples of your inputs and outputs, with actual results and desired results. Also, try `set -x` for debugging output to see what it's actually doing,

Comment: Make sure to note Walter's answer, addressing the more relevant point.

Answer (score 2):

`k` is assigned before the loop with `i`

```
i="1"
# introduce K var because the files are numbered as 0001 ... 0100
k=$(printf '%03d' $i)
while [  $i -le 100 ]; do
   ...
   ((i++))
   ...
done
```

Move the assignment to `k` inside the loop.
Alternative:

```
for ((i=1;i<100;i++)); do
   k=$(printf '%03d' ${i})
   ...
```

Comment: exactly! that is why my method did not worked... by the way could you explain in your example how really this looping method works "for ((i=1;i<9999;i++)); do"  ?

Comment: This is just a while loop starting with `i=1`, adding 1 in each loop and stopping at 9999. You should remove `((i++))` inside the loop, since incrementing is already done.